# Writing a line of code with Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium4

I've been having trouble creating a function in python using selenium to click a button on a webpage.

I'm following a tutorial that is out of date. In the tutorial the code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-value="39455542968391"]')
```

Now, I know that selenium has changed how this is done but I am struggling to figure out the correct way of going about it.

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=('//button[@class="nice-select open"]').click()
```

this line gives the error:

```
unexpected EOF while parsing
```

and

```
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@class="nice-select open"].click()
```

this line gives the error:

```
name "EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format of code from [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-value="39455542968391"]')
```

In [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) needs to be written as:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nice-select open']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="nice-select open"]').click()
```

You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Hey mate, how does one define 'By' as i am getting that error. Sorry, i'm quite new to this.